# Нужно найти произведение элементов массива, расположенных между минимальным и максимальным элементом массива.(не включая максимум и минимум)

Tags: c

```
int A[12];
int i;
int max=-100000;
int min=100000;
int n=12;
int im, jm;
for (i = 0; i<n; i++) 
{
    printf("A[%d] = ", i);
    scanf("%d", &A[i]);                                         
} 
for (i = 0; i<n; i++)                                           
printf("%d ", A[i]);    
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    if(A[i]>max)
    {
        max=A[i];
        im=i;
    }
    if(A[i]<min)
    {
        min=A[i];
        jm=i;
    }
}   
int proz=1;
if (im>jm)
{
    for(i=jm; i<=im; i++)
    {
        proz*=A[i];
    } 
}
else if(jm>im)
{
    for(i=jm; i<=im; i++)
    {
        proz*=A[i];
    }
}
printf("\n Произв. элементов массива расположенных между максимумом и минимумом: %d", proz)
getch();
return 0;
```

Comment: А вопрос то в чем? Если что не работает - то что конкретно, при каких входных данных etc etc...

Comment: А с чего Вы решили, что минимальный элемент будет меньше ста тысяч? А если больше? вся программа псу под хвост...

Answer (score 1):

У вас наверное переполнение?
Ищите произведение как `double`.

Еще - вам же сказано "не включая максимум и минимум", а вы что пишете?

```
for(i=jm; i<=im; i++)
```

Включая! замените на

```
for(i=jm+1; i< im; i++)
```

А еще лучше использовать предопределенные константы:

```
int max = INT_MIN;
int min = INT_MAX;
```